# setBit java method using bit shifting and hexadecimal code - question

Tags: bit-manipulation, hex

I am having trouble understanding what is happening in the two lines with the 0xFF7F and the one below it.  There is a link here that explains it to some degree.
http://www.herongyang.com/java/Bit-String-Set-Bit-to-Byte-Array.html
I don't know if 0xFF7F>>posBit) & oldByte) & 0x00FF
are supposed to be 3 values 'AND'ed together or how this is supposed to be read. If anyone can clarify what is happening here a little better, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
private static void setBit(byte[] data,
                               final int pos,
                               final int val) {
        int posByte = pos/8;
        int posBit = pos%8;
        byte oldByte = data[posByte];
        oldByte = (byte) (((0xFF7F>>posBit) & oldByte) & 0x00FF);
        byte newByte = (byte) ((val<<(8-(posBit+1))) | oldByte);
        data[posByte] = newByte;
    }
```

passed into this method as parameters from a selectBits method was setBit(out,i,val);
out = is byte[] out = new byte[numOfBytes]; (numOfBytes can be 7 in this situation)
i = which is number [57], the original number from the PC1 int array holding the 56-integers.
val = which is the bit taken from the byte array from the getBit() method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `0xFF7F` is `1111 1111 0111 1111`. This is shifted right by an amount of bits calculated from the bit you pass as a parameter (so the one you want to set).

If you specify third bit `posBit = 3 % 8 = 3` so

```
0xFF7F 1111 1111 0111 1111
>> 3   0001 1111 1110 1111
```

this value is then ANDed with the original byte you are modifying, the result is that every bit is kept equal to `oldBit` original bit except the one that is anded with the `0` bit, suppose you have for example `oldByte == 0111 1010`, you'll obtain:

```
    0111 1010
&   1110 1111
-------------
    0110 1010
```

Then the value is anded with `0xFF` just to discard any bit that doesn't fit a byte (because it's at least the ninth bit) before doing the cast.

Comment: What is the significance of the hex numbers though?  Why was 0xFF7F and 0x00FF chosen in this case?

Comment: They are _masks_, they are used with AND operator to select just some bits. In the first case 0xFF7F is used because you want to set a specified bit so you have all 1s except the one you want to work with (that is shifted according to __pos__). While 0x00FF is used to select just the lowest byte of a pair of bytes, since it selects just the lower 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this would be:

```
private static void setBit(byte[] data, int index, boolean value)
{
    final int byteIndex = index / 8;
    final int bitIndex = 7 - (index % 8);

    final byte mask = (byte) (1 << bitIndex);
    final byte valueBit = value ? mask : 0;

    data[byteIndex] = (byte) ((data[byteIndex] & ~mask) | valueBit);
}
```